# Mongodb : convert and sort date to timestamp

Tags: mongodb, date, timestamp, subtraction

I have a database in Mongodb 3.6, with a field "date.created" in ISODate (example : 2020-12-08T10:41:23.000+00:00)
I want to find only results greater than 1607383475.

I tried this command but it doesn't seem to work...

```
{
  "$expr": {
    "$gt": [
      { "$subtract": ["$date.created", new Date("1970-01-01")] },
      1607383475
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: The result of $subtract is in milliseconds.

Comment: *facepalm* thx...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSM is right, subtract is in milliseconds. I just had to convert my filter (*1000)...